# What is the recommended way to implement admins in a webapp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications, admin

I know of 2 ways to implement admins:

1. add admin role flag to the user entity
2. add a new admin entity

I don't know if there are more ways of doing it

**1. Does it matter in terms of admin usability? security?**

**2. which is easier to scale or maintain?**

for a rails-specific (but not limited to) sub-question

**Is using a premade admin services such as active_admin or adminium are worth it for the long run (heavy use application, not small sized), or would it just be better to make my own admin panel and incrementally add features as I need them?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to that question depends on your needs for a particular project.

Using the **premade admin services** makes life easier as what you can do is to customize the services by the help of ease that they provide and then use them in your application.

In [ActiveAdmin railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=comments), there is a video about `ActiveAdmin` that shows that how it is very customizable. Apart from that there are comments by various people in the `railscasts` from their experience about its usage.

This will clearly give you the idea in the right direction.

There is also a very good [article](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/11/20/admin-interfaces-for-rails-apps-railsadmin-vs-activeadmin/) by batsov which explains the differences between RailsAdmin and ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Again, much of this appears to be plagiarized from others, like this comment here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin?view=comments. I'm removing this until you edit this with proper attribution everywhere for the language you stole from others.

Answer (score 1):

**Short version:** Do it yourself with the admin role flag. For security do not allow mass assignment of this flag. Build your own admin interface, especially for a big project nothing premade will suit your needs.

**Long Version:**
I haven't actually used any of the premade admin services as in general my experience has shown me that my users are either normal/admin or semi-admin.

Having your own flag means that you have full control over how to add admin users.

Example: some apps I have allowed anyone with admin access to make anyone else an admin.

Rails allows you to quickly scaffold/build your own custom admin interface and here I can't see anything 'off the shelf' beating the add as you go/need mentality as the end result will be custom built to fully suit your needs vs spending your time with an admin interface that you have to customize yourself.